# I'm trying to understand the syntax of this cartesian-product function in Clojure

Tags: syntax, clojure

Here's some code for a cartesian product, it can be two lists, two vectors, or any number of combinations of the two. I'd really appreciate help with the second, fourth, and final lines, explaining what each line is doing

```clj
(defn cartesian-product ;function name definition
      ([] '(())) ;need help understanding this
      ([xs & more] ; at least two variables, xs is one of them
       (mapcat #(map (partial cons %) ;mapcat means a create a concatenated map of the following
                                      ;still trying to figure out partial, but cons takes a
                                      ;variable and puts it in front of a sequence
                     (apply cartesian-product more)) ; this is the sequence that is mapped
                                                     ; using (partial cons %)
               xs))) ;not sure what this is here for
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a reworked version that illustrates what is going on (and how):

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.core tupelo.test))

;----------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Lesson: how map & mapcat work
(defn dup [x]
  "Return 2 of the arg in a vector"
  [x x])

(dotest
  (let [nums [0 1 2]]
    (is= (mapv inc nums) [1 2 3])
    (is= (mapv dup nums) [[0 0] ; like a matrix, 2-D
                          [1 1]
                          [2 2]])

    ; mapcat glues together the inner "row" vectors. So the result is 1-D instead of 2-D
    (is= (mapcat dup nums) [0 0 1 1 2 2])))
```

then the reworked code

```
;----------------------------------------------------------------------------
(def empty-matrix [[]]) ; 0 rows, 0 cols

(defn cartesian-product ;function name definition
  "When called with 1 or more sequences, returns a list of all possible combinations
  of one item from each collection"
  ([]     ; if called with no args
   empty-matrix) ; return an empty matrix

  ; if called with 1 or more args,
  ([xs    ; first arg is named `xs` (i.e. plural for x values)
    & more] ; all other args are wrapped in a list named `more`
   (let [recursion-result (apply cartesian-product more) ; get cartesian prod of sequences 2..N
         inner-fn         (fn [arg] (map ; for each recursion-result
                                       (partial cons arg) ; glue arg to the front of it
                                       recursion-result))
         ; for each item in the first sequence (xs), glue to front of 
         ; each recursion result and then convert 2D->1D
         output           (mapcat inner-fn xs)]
     output)))
```

and some unit tests to show it in action

```
(dotest
  (is= (cartesian-product [1 2 3]) [[1] [2] [3]])

  (is= (cartesian-product [1 2 3] [:a :b])
    [[1 :a]
     [1 :b]
     [2 :a]
     [2 :b]
     [3 :a]
     [3 :b]])

  (is= (cartesian-product [1 2 3] [:a :b] ["apple" "pea"])
    [[1 :a "apple"]
     [1 :a "pea"]
     [1 :b "apple"]
     [1 :b "pea"]
     [2 :a "apple"]
     [2 :a "pea"]
     [2 :b "apple"]
     [2 :b "pea"]
     [3 :a "apple"]
     [3 :a "pea"]
     [3 :b "apple"]
     [3 :b "pea"]]))
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a reason why we return an empty matrix instead of an empty vector? or would an empty vector/list work the same?

Comment: @ForestH11 It's very important that the base case be `[[]]` or `'(())` or something like that. Cartesian product asks "how many ways are there to choose one element from each of these lists?", and for zero lists, there *is* one way to do it: choose no elements, yielding an empty list. If you used `[]` instead, you would be claiming there's no way to get a result, which will collapse all the recursive calls to nothing.

Comment: Nit: In `[xs & more]`, `more` is a list, not a vector, as the comment claims.